# How do I divide a $p$-adic number by a non-$p$-adic number?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Lets say I have a $p$-adic number 4|2 (-3, base 5), where 4 is the repeating part, how do I divide this number by, for example, 13 (base 10 so 23 base 5)? Can this be generalized as a formula for any $p$-adic number a|b divided by c, where a is the repeating part, b is the non-repeating part and c is an integer?

I know that the answer of my example, 4|2 (base 5 $p$-adic) divided by 13 (base 10 integer), is the $p$-adic number 1034 without a non_repeating part, but how do I get here?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Your question title is misleading: The things you divide by are, of course, *also* $p$-adic numbers. You seem to want to say they have "no repeating part", but for what it's worth, they do: they have a repeating string of $0$'s. (So by the way, everything you do here seems to only involve rational numbers, just written as $p$-adics.)